# jquery code for side navigation panel with active class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('.navigation-main').find('li').has('ul').children('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Collapsible
    $(this).parent('li').not('.disabled').not($('.sidebar-xs').not('.sidebar-xs-indicator').find('.navigation-main').children('li')).toggleClass('active').children('ul').slideToggle(250);

    // Accordion
    if ($('.navigation-main').hasClass('navigation-accordion')) {
        $(this).parent('li').not('.disabled').not($('.sidebar-xs').not('.sidebar-xs-indicator').find('.navigation-main').children('li')).siblings(':has(.has-ul)').removeClass('active').children('ul').slideUp(250);
    }
});
```

above is my javascript.

HTML part is,

```
 <div class="sidebar-category sidebar-category-visible">
                            <div class="category-content no-padding">
                                <ul class="navigation navigation-main navigation-accordion">

                                    <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/site/index"><i class="icon-home4"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#"><i class="icon-cogs"></i><span>Settings</span></a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/core/institution/create">Add Institution Details</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/core/academic/create">Academic Details</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/site/import">Student Import</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/site/employeeimport">Employee Import</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/core/privilege/create">Privileges</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/core/assignclass/create">Assign <?php echo Yii::app()->params['course']; ?>s</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php/site/users">Users</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
```

The code is worked for my navigation panel. But after reloading the page to selected submenu, all accordian will close. Code for navigation panel is written in seperate file and include to each page. I want the active class to set to the recently clicked menu after redirection

Comment: Where is your html markup ?

Comment: how much will you pay us to do this?

Comment: Why cant you put the entire code markup+js+css in the live editor ?

Comment: live editor? where is it?